# Exporting image from Google Earth Engine to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro, export, sentinel-2

I'm using false colour images of Swir_Nir_Green, which are the bands of B11, B8, B3 in Sentinel-2. I want to export them from Google Earth Engine and use them in ArcGIS. Even though I'm doing exactly the same thing, the first (left) image is not what I want. The right image is the correct one. Does anyone knows why this happens?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[5.549039555528434,52.56056893602342], 
[5.538739872911247,52.493729732674105], [5.622510624864372,52.492475526046704], 
[5.629377079942497,52.55931663656637] , [5.549039555528434,52.56056893602342]]]);


var image1 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200316T104709_20200316T105222_T31UFU").select('B11',
'B8', 'B3').clip(geometry);
var image2 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200303T103829_20200303T104450_T31UFU").select('B11', 
'B8', 'B3').clip(geometry);

Export.image.toDrive({
image: image1,
description: "first",
scale:10, 
fileFormat: "GeoTiff"
});


Export.image.toDrive({
image: image2,
description: "second",
scale:10, 
fileFormat: "GeoTiff"
});
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a paper on natural colour representation of satellite imagery:

Blaž Sovdat, Miha Kadunc, Matej Batič, Grega Milčinski,
Natural color representation of Sentinel-2 data, 
Remote Sensing of Environment, Volume 225, May 2019, Pages 392-402
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2019.01.036

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425719300422

Comment: For Landsat I use the following natural color formula: R=band5, G=0.5xband7+0.75xband4,B=band4

Answer (score 1):

In GEE they seem to be correct.

[image: image comparison]

1) Are you sure ArcGIS is using the same wavebands?

2) I would consider re-exporting and double checking you really are using the same code. It looks like the incorrect image has the same waveband assigned to red and blue channels, and I think it is B11. This is what that might look like in GEE..

[image: incorrect image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in GEE they are correct! The problem was in Acgis Pro, for the one image.  Im not sure which wavebands it uses. However, I was advised to change the stretching, and assign new values for the max values of Red, Green, Blue, and it works!

Comment: Great! Nice one    \ (•◡•) /